# How should a desktop application continuously poll a server for updates?

Tags: websocket, server-side

I'm writing a desktop application that needs to respond to a change on my server that could happen at any time, and I want the application to be always running whenever the computer is logged in.  Is there a way that is considered most standard or ways that should be avoided?  Several solutions I have considered are:

- Sending requests to the server twice per second (This is approximately the response time I would like)
- Opening a websockets connection so that there's just an open pipe the server can write to.

If the server just returns an error or a short short message whenever theres no data, would it be bad to use the first option? Would that affect other network activity on the network?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Mark Setchell said, avoid unnecessary polling.

WebSocket is not just for browsers. Desktop applications can also use WebSocket. If your application establishes a connection to the server, facilitated by WebSocket, then it can receive data or events asynchronously. No polling.

Now your desktop application can sit there, and whenever it receives an event or data from the server, it can take whatever action you desire.

> But how would I notify the desktop client without starting a server on the client and opening the client's firewall for incoming connections?

Using WebSocket in this way also prevents your client opening up an inbound port in their firewall, as they are the one that initiated the (outbound) connection.

Comment: I couldn't have asked for a better answer; this is exactly what I was looking for!! Just one small follow-up question: once I establish a websocket connection with the server, absolutely no data is exchanged until I explicitly send it (either from the client or the server) right?  There is no small overhead data needed to keep the connection alive?

Comment: Correct. Data only traverses the connection of the client sends something or the server sends something. Note that this applies to the WebSocket layer and above. Underneath, TCP may be doing some back-and-forth communication, but that won't appear to your application.

In practice, intermediaries like firewalls or proxies may terminate an idle connection if they detect no activity over a certain period of time. Therefore you may find it useful to periodically send messages over the WebSocket connection so it appears there is activity.

The WebSocket protocol has ping/pong you can use, too.

Answer (score 0):

If the server knows when there are updates available it would be best placed to notify your desktop application surely? That would avoid unnecessary polling.

In any case, I would probably have a separate thread that exclusively communicates with the server and (after maybe locking a semaphore) updates some global variables that the main thread is using whenever updates are available.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I want to do! But how would I notify the desktop client without starting a server on the client and opening the client's firewall for incoming connections?